# My Batis custom TypeHandler does not work properly

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, h2, mybatis

I have an issue with an IBatis custom mapper with H2.

I have an H2 TEXT column (CLOB) that I have a String in and when I run a query:

```
@Select("select issue, count(*) from complaints WHERE company = #{companyName} group by issue order by 2 desc;")
fun getIssueCountsByCompanyName(@Param("companyName") companyName: String): List<Pair<String, Long>>
```

I have a custom TypeMapper that I can see running and extracting the String from the CLOB properly:

```
@MappedJdbcTypes(JdbcType.VARCHAR, JdbcType.CLOB, JdbcType.CHAR, JdbcType.NVARCHAR)
@MappedTypes(String::class)
class ClobTypeHandler: TypeHandler<String> {
    override fun setParameter(ps: PreparedStatement?, i: Int, parameter: String?, jdbcType: JdbcType?) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    fun getFromCol(col: Any?): String{
        if(col == null){ return "" }
        if(col is JdbcClob){
            val returnValue =StreamUtils.copyToString(col.asciiStream, UTF_8)
            // Examining with debugger shows `returnValue` is the correct String here
            return returnValue
        }
        else {
            return col.toString()
        }
    }

    override fun getResult(rs: ResultSet?, columnName: String?): String {
        return getFromCol(rs?.getObject(columnName))
    }

    override fun getResult(rs: ResultSet?, columnIndex: Int): String {
        return getFromCol(rs?.getObject(columnIndex))
    }

    override fun getResult(rs: CallableStatement?, columnIndex: Int): String {
        return getFromCol(rs?.getObject(columnIndex))
    }
}
```

Here's my test:

```
@Test
fun test_getIssues(){
    var issueCounts = complaintMapper.getIssueCounts();
    var issueCount = issueCounts.get(0)

    assertFalse(issueCount.first.startsWith("clob"))
}
```

I get this error:

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcClob cannot be cast to java.lang.String
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcClob cannot be cast to java.lang.String

So, it looks like somehow MYBatis is calling the method like I expect and the method is returning the correct String value, but when MYBatis is putting the data into the Object that it's returning it is putting the wrong value into it (the CLOB instead of the String it got from the mapper)

What is going on here? Is it the aggregation that's causing it, I don't understand...

Comment: Do you really need a custom type handler? If you want a `String` as a result, the built-in `StringTypeHandler` is sufficient in most cases, I believe. Assuming you need to use the custom type handler, please provide a small executable project like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues). With your explanation, `ClassCastException` does not make sense if the `returnValue` already is a `String`, so we better have a repro.

Comment: So the StringTypeHandler from MYBatis returns stuff with "clob 1: 'The actual string'" - so yes, I need the handler for H2 - I figured out if I'm using my generic Pair class I need to specify the handler for the column to be my custom handler via the @Result annotation

Comment: @ave - I guess what I'm getting at is that the oob handler from mybatis does not handle pulling an H2 TEXT column out of a result set and putting it into a generic that is expecting a String. I have a small repo with a 2 column table that shows this behavior - where should I post it? As a bug in the github repo?

Comment: I'm happy to know that you have found a solution! I'm not sure why the built-in StringTypeHandler does not work for you, though. Just FYI, the easiest way to share your project is to create a new repo with your GitHub account and upload the project there.

Comment: Based on the mybatis github StringTypeHandler.java class, it's the H2 driver's `ResultSet .getString` method (when called on a CLOB column) does not read from `col.asciiStream` - it appears to just be calling the `toString` method and getting that String

Comment: @ave fwiw here's the repo demonstrating the issue: https://github.com/mikebski/mybatis-h2-text-clob-fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this fixes it:

```
    @Results(Result(column = "first", property = "first", typeHandler = H2ClobTypeHandler::class))
    @Select("select issue as first, count(*) as second from complaints WHERE company = #{companyName} group by issue order by 2 desc;")
    fun getIssueCountsByCompanyName(@Param("companyName") companyName: String): List<Pair<String, Long>>
```

It has something to do with selecting into a generic that is typed with a String when the H2 column is a TEXT type.